# How to add javascript file in <head> in this condition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xhtml, content-management-system

Only if `form` action is `/?cms_mode=edit`

```
<body id="home">
    <form method="post" action="/?cms_mode=edit" id="main">
    </form>
</body>
```

then a js file `edit.js` should be added into head, otherwise not.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="edit.js"></script>
</head>
```

Is it possible through jquery/javascript?

And edit.js flie should be added after all other .js file

Comment: Why don't you handle this on the server-side?

Comment: because i don't have those rights. i need this for particular site on multi-site CMS

Answer (score 5):

If you have to do it on the client-side in JavaScript, you may want to try the following:

```
var newScript;

if (document.getElementById('main').action.indexOf('?cms_mode=edit') >= 0) {  
   newScript = document.createElement('script');
   newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
   newScript.src = 'edit.js';
   document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(newScript);
}
```

Comment: Is it 100% certain that the browser will pick up the DOM change and load the script?

Comment: @Mikael: Yes. Dynamic script insertion is a commonly used pattern. It is also used for [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP).

Comment: @Daniel: I've inserted scripts before, and then called them, but didn't know that loading also worked. Cool :D

Comment: @Daniel Vassallo - Ok i will try this

Comment: @Daniel Vassallo - will it give error if action="/" is something else?

Comment: @metal-gear-solid: No it shouldn't. `document.getElementById('main').action` should give you the absolute URL of the action, if one is set. We used `indexOf` and not `==`, because of the absolute url.